# How to get internal audio stream using python on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, audio-streaming

How do I capture the system audio output stream using python on Linux(Ubuntu)? What libraries are available? A sample code would be helpful.

Comment: Had a look on pulseaudio?

Comment: Yeah. But I not sure how to get the audio "stream" using PulseAudio.